# Implementing Redux in React using the create-react-app -Simple question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app

Is is correct to pass a reducer as props when i'm using a rootreducer ?

This is my rootReducer.js :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import simpleReducer from './simpleReducer';
import messageReducer from './messageReducer';
import NewReducer from './NewReducer';
export default combineReducers({
 simpleReducer,messageReducer,NewReducer

});
```

And this is one of my action creators addMessage.js

```
export const addMessage = (message) => dispatch => {
dispatch({
type: 'ADD',
message: message
})
}
```

**Here is the first reducer messageReducer.js**

```js
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD':
        return [
          ...state,
          action.message
        ];
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

And here is another one simpleReducer.js

```js
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
     case 'SIMPLE_ACTION':
      return {
       result: action.payload
      }
     default:
      return state
    }
   }
```

And finally here is my last reducer NewReducer.js

```js
export default (state = '', action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'AnyThing':
        return action.WhatToDisplay;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

Here is my mapping in the App.js

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
...state
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({

simpleAction: () => dispatch(simpleAction()),

submitNewMessage: (message) => {
dispatch(addMessage(message))
},
NewAction: () => dispatch(NewAction())
})
```

And here is my ِApp Component.Notice my last 2 h2 tags as well as my ul tag .Without me adding the reducer at the end of the prop , it doesn't work.So
is what i'm doing right ? or is there another way to show the redux state in
my react ?.Note that i currently have no errors and the code functions well.I
just wana know if what i am doing is right or wrong and if there is a better 
syntax to show the redux state in my create react app.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: ''

    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.submitMessage = this.submitMessage.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    });
    }
    submitMessage() {
    this.props.submitNewMessage(this.state.input);
    this.setState({
      input: ''
    });
    }
    simpleAction = (event) => {
    this.props.simpleAction();
    }
    localNormalFunction=(event)=>{
     this.props.NewAction()
    }
    render() {
    return (
      <div >
    <h1>fjasgdasdsg</h1>
    <button onClick={this.simpleAction}>Test redux action</button>
    <pre>
    {
    JSON.stringify(this.props)
    }
         </pre>
         <h2>Type in a new Message:</h2>
        <input
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/> 
          <button onClick={this.submitMessage}>Submit</button>
           <ul>
          {this.props.messageReducer.map( (message,idx) => {
              return (
                 <li key={idx}>{message}</li>
              )
            })
          }
          </ul><br/><br/>
          <button onClick={this.localNormalFunction}>dsadsdsa</button>
          <h2>{this.props.NewReducer}</h2>
          <h2>{this.props.simpleReducer.result}</h2>

          </div>
            );
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better practice to get only the props you need from redux in each component. If you pass the whole redux state in mapStateToProps then whenever anything in redux changes you will have everything rerendering even if nothing you use changed.

One common reason you might be getting errors is that you are trying to use the props in render and they get instantiated afterwards.

Try this give default values to the props if you can't get them from redux:

```
App.defaultProps = {
  result: '',
  NewReducer: '',
  messageReducer: []
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  result: state.simpleReducer.result,
  NewReducer: state.NewReducer,
  messageReducer: state.messageReducer
})
```

and then change this.props.simpleReducer.result to this.props.result

Comment: that was my initial code but i failed to implement it and winded up with errors, only this was able to remove them,if it is not much trouble, can you please edit my code ?

Comment: can you please add the initial state of each reducer you have in your post?

Comment: Done.I added the rest of the reducers.

Comment: I have updated my answer but i don't see the messageReducer still in your post, just the action creator

Comment: My mistake sorry, i just added it and made it bold

Comment: Is there any info about the errors that can help us?

Comment: When i make my mapping like this : const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  messages: state
 }) .................And my ul like this >>> this.props.messages.map...........i get this error: TypeError: this.props.messages.map is not a function

Comment: This happens because the first time the map function is being run, this.props.messages is not an Array. From the code you have posted you should get messages like  const mapStateToProps = state => ({ messages: state.messagesReducer })

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm arguing with you especially when i'm still a newbie in redux and react but......isn't that pretty much the same thing ?........instead of me specifying that the state here comes from the mesageReducer in the ul tag , you specified it in the mapstatetoprops method so what's the difference ? . i thought i shouldn't mention the reducer at all in my react and that's why i made this post.mmm maybe u mean if i made the specification in the mapstatetoprops , the states in the messageReducer will be the only ones transferred to the react ?.I would be very grateful if elaborated more.